# hiding label on clicking on it using jquery

Tags: asp.net, jquery

i am using a label

```
<asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text="" BorderStyle="Solid"></asp:Label>
```

in script part iam doing something

```
$('span[id$=lblMessage]').click(function()
    {
        $('#lblMessage').hide(slow);
    });
```

but it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function pageLoad(sender, args)
    {
        $('#<%=lblMessage.ClientID %>').click(function()
        {
            $(this).fadeOut('slow');
        });
    }
```

now its working fine

Answer (score 4):

this should work, you should enclose the `slow` with quote

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#<%= lblMessage.ClientID %>").click(function() {
        $(this).hide("slow");
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Very good point. I have updated my answer to reflect as well. I will upvote bt I have reached my daily limit today.

Answer (score 2):

Have you surrounded by $(document).ready?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#<%= lblMessage.ClientID %>").click(function() {
        $(this).hide("slow");
    });
});
```

An alternative is to use a class selector. That way, you don't limit yourself to a single hideable label. You can hide anything that has this class.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblMessage" cssClass="hideable" runat="server" Text="" BorderStyle="Solid"></asp:Label>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".hideable").click(function() {
        $(this).hide("slow");
    });
});
```